# Imagick auto cropping transparent area resulting in wrong sizes

Tags: imagemagick, imagick

I have a transparent PNG with a transparent background.

[image]

When I will load the image with Imagick all the transparent area around the image will be ignored.

```
$background = new Imagick("./frames/0.gif");
```

So this particular 350x200 image become a 189x184.

[image]

But I need that the canvas size will not modified or I will lose reference with other info.

Someone can help me?

Comment: Post a link to your original image. Auto cropping should not happen with your 0.gif. That makes no sense to me. Are you sure you are working with the image that has the transparent background and not one that has been cropped already. What is the version of Imagick and the version of Imagemagick? Is that your full Imagick code? If not, how do you know the size is smaller than it should be?

Comment: CONTINUED: Was the gif frame coalesced? If not it could be optimized, which would make it appear to be smaller. Optimized gif animations have smaller frames when the background is constant. The gif knows when played to fill it out to proper full size. If you extract frames from a gif animation, be sure to coalesce the frames to get their full size format. See http://us3.php.net/manual/en/imagick.coalesceimages.php